# which one is best for use in delphi i.e use of package or dll

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-7

I'd like to use a .dll with a delphi application, but I'm curious if a delphi package is more flexible than dll?

Comment: Define "confused", "more flexible", "delpshi" :), and "correct suggestion" after RTFMs -- the properties of a Delphi package are well-defined in the documentation. I'd suggest you refine your question afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can read this article on my Blog: "[DLL's, BPL's Static and dynamic loading, and Packages in Runtime](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?p=803)"; Is 's writed in Spanish but you can try the Automatic translation (on right part of the page).

Basically BPL is an extension of a DLL. It's a DLL with some things added.

(POSITIVE) If you use BPL's you can do more things with the DLL. More power. You can use RTTI (you must build your applicaction with runtime package for accesss RTTI).

(NEGATIVE) If you use BPL's with more powerfull, you can only use it with Delphi, no with other languages.

If you're sure that you only use it with Deplhi, I think that you must use BPL. Search samples about RTTI, RegisterClasses, GetClass method, LoadPackage (for dynamic load),...

Regards.

Escuse-me for my poor english. It's not my natural language.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing excactly what you mean, and believing you are a newbie (so I may omit some specialized aspects), and implying you know what a DLL is:

**The first and foremost reason to build a package is authoring a design-time component.**

You can do quite everything (well..almost...) that a package does just as well with DLLs -- except for the design-time stuff.

Additionally, you can package *multiple* compiled packages into *one* Borland Package Library (BPL file) without having the design-time features in mind. If you think deploying and runtime-binding one BPL is better than various DLLs, go for it. The primary purpose is design-time support, though.

Comment: Packages are just DLLs with native VCL support built-in. They are not just limited to implementing design-time components. Runtime code can use them to implement plugins and such. The main reason to use a Package over a plain DLL is to GET VCL SUPPORT! This is important if the Package exposes VCL objects for the calling EXE to use. This gets harder to get right, and can cause many problems, when using a plain DLL instead.

Comment: Agree. However, you can do all that using DLLs only, you just will have a hard time doing so. But try to stuff a DLL into the VCL palette, i.e. do design-time stuff without packages.

Comment: -1 A BPL is a package - not a package library. A BPL is a collection of units. There was once a tool to create package collections, and deploy them. And remember your DLL may end up to have a separate copy of the RTL/VCL and some functions may not work as expected (i.e. "is" may not work if the same class declaration happen to exists both in the exe and a DLL). Packages are tightly integrated with Delphi, and their scope goes far beyond adding new components to the IDE, and it's not its primary purpose. Delphi itself is built using runtime packages.

Comment: And don't I compile multiple .DPKs (Delphi Packages) into multiple .DCPs (Delphi Compiled Packages), and I construct a BPL from one or more .DCPs? I might forget something here, but...?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau >>They are not just limited to implementing design-time components. Runtime code can use them to implement plugins and such. << Sure. However, if a newbie asks me what he will ever use it for in the near future, I'd say "first occasion: design-time component deployment".

Comment: A .bpl contains the actual "runtime" code. A .dcp contains the compiled package header/symbols informations. There's one .bpl and one .dcp generated from each package source (.dpk). DCPs reference in a packages (requires) are just "dependencies" informations, they don't mean they are "included". Packages only contains the unit they are created from, and if two packages contains the same unit they can't be loaded at the same time.

Comment: Seems like the guy asking is not worth the hassle since no answer is accepted :(

Answer (score 0):

Packages are special DLLs that can export classes, while DLLs can only export functions. Yes, you can write a DLL function that creates and instance of a given class, but you can't use a class declared in a DLL (unless using some hacks maybe), while you can use a class declared in a package directly. Packages "know" about Delphi object architecture, while DLLs don't. On the other end, DLLs can be used from any language able to use them, while packages are Delphi-specific.